# How to ignore returns/enters in the input

Tags: python

When I paste some text into python that has a return in it (a piece of paragraphed text for example), the input stops there as python thinks that I've pressed enter.

What I want it to do is only take in the input once its gone through all of it, not just up to the first return.

Here is an example:

Code:

```
text = input('Enter: ')
print(text)
```

Input:

```
In another moment down went Alice after it, never once considering how
in the world she was to get out again.

The rabbit-hole went straight on like a tunnel for some way, and then
dipped suddenly down, so suddenly that Alice had not a moment to think
about stopping herself before she found herself falling down a very deep
well.
```

Output:

```
In another moment down went Alice after it, never once considering how
```

Comment: How do you know when input has stopped? If you do `sys.stdin.read()`, it will read all text until a `^D` (EOF).

Answer (score 0):

While the received line isn't empty, grab another line.

```
input_received = True
input_string = ""
while input_received:
  new_input = input()
  if new_input:
    input_string += new_input
  else:
    input_received = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep taking readings for the next line with `input()` whilst they user has actually entered text. When they have entered text, you need to remember to concatenate this text onto the `text` string **along with a `\n`** as this makes sure that the paragraph maintains its form.

The steps outlined above can be easily achieved with a `while` loop which uses the fact that an empty string evaluates to **`False`**:

```
text = ""
inpt = input()
while inpt:
    inpt = input()
    text += inpt + "\n"
```

So if I entered something like:

```
Hello, this is line 1 and 
we are onto the next line 
and now onto the third is
this not a cool text para
```

then ran `print(text)`, I would get the proper output on different lines of:

```
Hello, this is line 1 and 
we are onto the next line 
and now onto the third is
this not a cool text para
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

print ('Enter: ', end='')
text = sys.stdin.readlines()[0].strip()
print(text)
```